# Wordpress 3.9 - required fields validation

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation

Maybe somebody can help: I have a custom form inside my plugin and I added to the fields the attribute 'required'. Then (without adding js to validate from my side) the tooltips and red borders appears -  and I can't find the corresponding script which does it. Where can I find this js function?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like the native HTML5 warning. HTML5 has in-built form validation these days, and the like of Firefox and Chrome support it.

Comment: Ooooh, you are so right - sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.